# How to fire a jquery function when selecting an auto complete item

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor

I have the following view inside my asp.net mvc razor view:-

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Technology2.Tag,new { @class = "pcolor"})
```

and i specify this jquery function to do an auto complete on the above TextBox:-

```
 $("#Technology2_Tag").autocomplete({
            minLength: 1, delay: 1000,
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "@Url.Content("~/Switch/AutoComplete2")",
```

and it is working well. but now i need to fire another jQuery function after the user select an auto complete item. i tried this , but did not work:-

```
 $("#Technology2_Tag").change(function () {
```

what i need is to fire the jQuery on the selected autocomplete item ?
Can anyone advice ?

Answer (score -1):

You'd use .select() Event instead on .change()
Here is the [JQuery Documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select)

```
$("#Technology2_Tag").change(function (event, ui) {....}
```